# How to keep React Native app running in background?

Tags: react-native

I want to keep track of the location of user using watchposition in react native and send that location to server is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use this https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation its pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this plugin [`react-native-background-timer`](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) to enable my app to run in background as well and get device location here is the sample code

```
BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

                this.setState({
                    startDrive: true,
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                });

                this.offlineHistoryManager(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            }, (error) => {

                LocationSwitch.enableLocationService(1000, true, () => {         //
                }, () => {         //
                },);
            }, {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000});
        }, 30000);
```